# Rolling join in data.table doesn't give desired output

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` (dt) with 3 columns ("`times`","`name`","`price`"). I aim to find the price when I input a number and a time value. However, when I input a time that is not in the dt I want to get the next (or the last) price that it had. 
I am doing this, but it doesn't seem to work as I get NA if the price is not in the dt.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
times = c("2017-02-13 07:02:45","2017-02-13 07:02:48","2017-02-13 07:02:49"),
name = c("name1", "name1", "name1"),
price = c(10,15,20)
)

setkey(dt, times, name)

nm = "name1"
tt = "2017-02-13 07:02:46"
dt[times == tt & name == nm]

pricelookup <- function(tt, nm, data = dt) {
dt[J(tt, nm), roll = TRUE][, price]
}
pricelookup(tt,nm)
```

Comment: @jaap thanks for the tip. Done

Comment: `dt[.(nm, tt), on=.(name, times), roll=-Inf]`? Rolling affects the last column joined on; and the roll= arg takes other values besides just TRUE.

Comment: @Frank many thanks for the help! where can I read more about this?

Comment: Np, glad it works! The documentation for the roll= argument in `?data.table` should cover it. This is a "rolling join" and the developers are planning a vignette on joins (https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944) but it's not out yet. I cover rolling joins very briefly in my notes, fwiw: http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#dt-joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a non-equi join is better. Using:

```
dt[CJ(tt, nm), on = .(times <= V1, name = V2)]
```

gives:

> ```
>                  times  name price
> 1: 2017-02-13 07:02:46 name1    10
> ```

In your function:

```
pricelookup <- function(tt, nm, data = dt) {
  dt[CJ(tt, nm), on = .(times <= V1, name = V2)][, price]
}
```

which now will give the correct output:

> ```
> > pricelookup(tt, nm)
> [1] 10
> ```

When you only want the first result for the join, add `mult = 'first'` to the join operation. To see what this does, compare the output of the following two joins:

> ```
> > dt[CJ(tt, nm), on = .(times >= V1, name = V2)]
>                  times  name price
> 1: 2017-02-13 07:02:46 name1    15
> 2: 2017-02-13 07:02:46 name1    20
>
> > dt[CJ(tt, nm), on = .(times >= V1, name = V2), mult = 'first']
>                  times  name price
> 1: 2017-02-13 07:02:46 name1    15
> ```

---

*Used data:*

```
dt <- data.table(
  times = as.POSIXct(c("2017-02-13 07:02:45","2017-02-13 07:02:48","2017-02-13 07:02:49"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
  name = c("name1", "name1", "name1"),
  price = c(10,15,20)
)

setkey(dt, times, name)

nm = "name1"
tt = as.POSIXct("2017-02-13 07:02:46", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```